# Flash AS3 Radio Player to play BBC Radio

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stream

am building a radio player in flash, and I need to get all the BBC Radio Stations working in the player.

I am trying to use their AAC Streams, I have a bit of ActionScript 3 code for reading AAC Streams, but this just doesnt seem to work with BBC Radio Streams. The error message I get is:
`NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound` but the very same stream works fine in WinAmp.

This is a sample AAC Stream I am trying to play (BBC Radio 3):

`http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_lc1_radio3_q?s=1334749463&e=1334763863&h=3bc870c82d1e1f360d8cfc1d296d97c2`

This is the AS3 Class I am using to play streams:

```
package play {

import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;

public class aacplay {

    private var netConn:NetConnection=new NetConnection();
    private var netStrm:NetStream;
    private var urlStr:String;

    public function aacplay(radiourl) {
        urlStr=radiourl;
        connect();
    }

    private function connect():void{
        netConn.close();
        netConn=new NetConnection();
        netConn.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatusHdlr);
        netConn.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR,asyncErrorHdlr);
            netConn.connect(null);
        }

        private function netStatusHdlr(e:NetStatusEvent):void{
            trace('netStatusHdlr:'+e.info.code);
            switch(e.info.code){
                case 'NetConnection.Connect.Success':
                    requestAudio();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function requestAudio():void{
            if(netStrm!==null){
                netStrm.close();
            }
            netStrm=new NetStream(netConn);
            netStrm.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatusHdlr);
            netStrm.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR,asyncErrorHdlr);
            netStrm.checkPolicyFile=false;
            netStrm.play(urlStr);
        }

        private function asyncErrorHdlr(e:AsyncErrorEvent):void{
            trace('asyncErrorHdlr:'+e);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am invoking the class with:

```
var aac:aacplay=new aacplay('http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_lc1_radio3_q?s=1334749463&e=1334763863&h=3bc870c82d1e1f360d8cfc1d296d97c2');
```

Can anyone tell me why I am unable to play the BBC Stream - is it a security issue? And if so, how do I get around this security issue?

Comment: going to the URL directly in a browser give unauthorized url

Comment: That is why I thought it could be a security issue. Do you know how I would go about getting around this? Would I have to arrange something with the BBC?

Comment: I do not know. Sorry. I have no idea what would give that server response from a public url. I would verify that the url is in fact correct. Then I would look at the encoding of the stream and verify that the player can indeed play that encoding.

Answer (score 1):

using `netConn.connect(null)` means that you will play local mp4 or flv file, or push data to the buffer manually utilize `NetStream.appendBytes()`

in this situation you need:

- open `URLSocket` to your url
- recieve the data
- parse it on the fly
- create `FLVTag` with `AAC` data in it, from previous step
- push this data to `NetStream.appendBytes()`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes()